# Use .htaccess to pass names and values

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to pass the variable names along with their values with .htaccess?
An example of this would be `foo.com/first/value/second/value2` would be written as `foo.com/index.php?first=value&second=value2`
The keys could change at any time so a new url could be `foo.com/newkey1/abc/newkey2/123` which would be `foo.com/index.php?newkey1=abc&newkey2=123`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Have a look at the following Htaccess rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^foo.com/index/(.*)/(.*)/$ foo.com/index.php?first=value&second=value2
```

you will have to write the link as

```
<a href="http://foo.com/<?php echo $value1; ?>/<?php echo $vaule2; ?>/">click here</a>
```

When you it will get executed it will appear as following in the browser.

```
foo.com/index/value1/value2
```

Then you can get it as

```
 $_REQUEST['first'];
 $_REQUEST['second'];
```

Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: The keys could change though, I have edited my question